# how to use rxgraph to generate graph

Tags: ros, rxgraph

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ｈｉ　Ｋｅｎ，
ｃａｎ　Ｉ　ｕｓｅ　ｒｘｇｒａｐｈ　ａｓ　ａ　ｌｉｂｒａｒｙ　ｏｒ　ｔｏｏｌ　ｔｏ　ｄｒａｗ　ｍｙ　ｏｗｎ　graph，　ｌｅｔ　ｓａｙ，　Ｉ　ｃａｎ　ｉｎｐｕｔ　ｍｙ　ｏｗｎ　ｄａｔａ　ｔｏｒｅｐｌａｃｅ　ｔｈｅ　ｎｏｄｅｓ　ａｎｄ　ｔｏｐｉｃｓ，　ｔｈｅｎ　ｇｅｎｅｒａｔｅ　ａ　ｔｏｔａｌｌｙ　ｎｅｗ　ｄｙｎａｍｉｃ　ｇｒａｐｈ　ｂａｓｅｄ　ｏｎ　ｔｈｅ　ｉｎｐｕｔｓ．
ｃｏｕｌｄ　ｙｏｕ　ｐｒｏｖｉｄｅ　ｓｏｍｅ　ｉｎｆｏｒｍａｔｉｏｎ　ｈｏｗ　ｔｏ　ｇｅｎｅｒａｔｅ　ｔｈｅ　ｒｘｇｒａｐｈ　ｌｉｋｅ　ｄｉａｇｒａｍ？
ｔｈａｎｋｓ　ｉｎ　ａｄｖａｎｃｅ！
Ｔａｏ

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11362/how-to-use-rxgraph-to-generate-graph/) by [Tao](https://answers.ros.org/users/1138/tao/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2011-09-29

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

rxgraph simply uses graphviz.  The viewer that rxgraph uses is called xdot, which sits on top of of graphviz.

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2011-09-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2